# Conditional "orderby" sort order in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In LINQ, is it possible to have conditional orderby sort order (ascending vs. descending).

Something like this (not valid code):

```
bool flag;

(from w in widgets
 where w.Name.Contains("xyz")
 orderby w.Id (flag ? ascending : descending)
 select w)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you build the expression incrementally you can do this. Generally easier using expressions rather than comprehension expressions:

```
var x = widgets.Where(w => w.Name.Contains("xyz"));
if (flag) {
  x = x.OrderBy(w => w.property);
} else {
  x = x.OrderByDescending(w => w.property);
}
```

(Assuming the Widget's `property` is basis of sort since you don't list one.)

Comment: how to do multiple Ordering with dynamic conditions if they are required or not.

Comment: Just need to use a different variable for the result of `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to keep the different return type; otherwise just add calls to the applicable `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending` LINQ operator.

Answer (score 19):

...Or do it all in one statement

```
bool flag;

var result = from w in widgets where w.Name.Contains("xyz")
  orderby
    flag ? w.Id : 0,
    flag ? 0 : w.Id descending
  select w;
```

Comment: If the underlying data is in SQL, this answer seems the most likely to use SQL's ORDERBY clause, but I don't know that for a fact.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a more general solution, that can be used for various conditional lambda expressions without breaking the flow of the expression.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IfThenElse<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> elements,
    Func<bool> condition,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> thenPath,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> elsePath)
{
    return condition()
        ? thenPath(elements)
        : elsePath(elements);
}
```

e.g.

```
var result = widgets
    .Where(w => w.Name.Contains("xyz"))
    .IfThenElse(
        () => flag,
        e => e.OrderBy(w => w.Id),
        e => e.OrderByDescending(w => w.Id));
```

Comment: This is awesome! You can modify this to make `elsePath` an optional parameter

Comment: You can simply use `e => e` for `elsePath` and the enumerable will be returned as is.

Comment: It is pretty nice, however I did a change since IEnumerable was forcing to retrieve items from the database, so instead of IEnumerable I used IQueryable.

Answer (score 9):

You can define a base query without the ordering, then order according to the flag:

```
var query=(from w in widgets
  where w.Name.Contains("xyz")
  select w);

var result = flag ?
  query.OrderBy(w =>w) :
  query.OrderByDescending(w = w);
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like the following:

```
var q = from i in list
         where i.Name = "name"
         select i;
if(foo)
     q = q.OrderBy(o=>o.Name);
else
     q = q.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Name);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the ordering property `Id` is a number (or supports the unary minus) one could also do:

```
bool ascending = ...

collection.Where(x => ...)
  .OrderBy(x => ascending ? x.Id : -x.Id)
  .Select(x => ...)

// LINQ query
from x in ...
orderby (ascending ? x.Id : -x.Id)
select ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Can also roll up Richard's answer into a convenient helper method, like so:

```
internal static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource,TKey>
        (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
         bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector)
                         : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource,TKey>
        (this IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
         bool ascending)
    {
        return ascending ? source.ThenBy(keySelector)
                         : source.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) NuGet [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) also provides extension methods to make [this](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/OrderBy.cs) more convenient.
It also provides many more helpful extension methods and is therefore a stable go-to in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do more complex ordering and still keep it short:

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>() { [1] = "z", [3] = "b", [2] = "c" };
    var condition =  true;
    var result = (condition ? dict.OrderBy(x => x.Key) : dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
        .Select(x => x.Value);
```