# Change order by depending on condition in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional “orderby” sort order in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606454/conditional-orderby-sort-order-in-linq)

Please tell me how can I sort the following query with different columns depending upon condition like now it is being sorted on OfferID descending,

```
var myoffer = (from b in MMEntities.OfferDisplays.AsExpandable().Where(pred)
                       where b.Offers.Accounts.AccountID == accountID && b.Offers.OfferID != 0  && !((from bb in MMEntities.OfferDisplays.AsExpandable().Where(pred)
                             where
                               bb.Offers.Accounts.AccountID == accountID && bb.Offers.OfferID != 0  orderby
                             bb.Offers.OfferID descending
                             select new
                             {
                                 bb.Offers.OfferID
                             }).Take(10)).Contains(new { b.Offers.OfferID }) &&
                         b.Offers.Accounts.AccountID == accountID orderby
                         b.Offers.OfferID descending
```

Comment: @Richard, No sir I want to sort both the queries using same parameter.

Comment: You can apply the same process to both queries. Splitting LINQ queries, thanks to their laziness, makes no difference to the overall process.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ? : operator in your `OrderBy' statement

`condition ? value1 : value2`  evaluates to `value 1` if the condition is true, and `value 2` if it is false.

Comment: Hi Sam, I have a parameter as "col" depending upon its value I need to change the oredering. like if col == "OfferName" then it should change the order as Title descending. Do you want me put it like this? "orderby col == "OfferName" ? bb.Title descending : bb.Offers.OfferID descending"

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**  IF you will use the same ordering argument twice:

You can maybe try and create a local param using `Let` :

```
var myofferUnsorted = (from b in MMEntities.OfferDisplays.AsExpandable().Where(pred)
                    **let OrderArg = b.Offers.OfferID**
                   where b.Offers.Accounts.AccountID == accountID && b.Offers.OfferID != 0  && !((from bb in MMEntities.OfferDisplays.AsExpandable().Where(pred)
                         where
                           bb.Offers.Accounts.AccountID == accountID && bb.Offers.OfferID != 0                                  orderby
                         OrderArg descending
                         select new
                         {
                             bb.Offers.OfferID
                         }).Take(10)).Contains(new { b.Offers.OfferID }) &&
                     b.Offers.Accounts.AccountID == accountID 
orderby
                         OrderArg  descending
```

And in this case you will have to embed the condition into the linq as :
`let OrderArg = flag ? b.Offers.OfferID : b.Offers.SmthElse`

Comment: I am planning to sort both the queries with same parameter. Can you please suggess something which will work like this?

Comment: Ok i guess you got your answer but donT forget to check the edit