# Linq order by conditional

Tags: c#, linq

I'm searching through a list of images and I want to find the "best fit". i.e., if the image set contains an imager taller than `H` pixels, I want to get the *shortest* image with a height greater than `H`, if the image set *does not* contain an image with a height bigger than `H`, then I just want to take the tallest overall image.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
var imageFile =
    from f in imageObj.Files
    orderby f.Height > height descending, f.Height ascending, f.Height descending
    select f;
```

Obviously this won't work -- I can't figure out how to put a conditional in there.

Any suggestions?

---

Please note that my question is different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606454/conditional-orderby-sort-order-in-linq) where the conditional can be pre-evaluated; mine depends on `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ordering by if a file is above a certain height, you can order by the distance from that height:

```
var imageFile =
    from f in imageObj.Files
    orderby f.Height > height descending, Math.Abs(f.Height - height) ascending
    select f;
```

Comment: Ooh..yes, this looks logically equivalent. I'm using linq-to-sql, will have to see which translates better.

Answer (score 6):

`order by f.Height > height ? f.Height : 1000000 - f.Height`

First go images higher than height, followed by images lower than height in reversed order.

Comment: clever. can't we just negate `f.Height` on the right though? `orderby f.Height > height ? f.Height : -f.Height`

Comment: @Mark That's what I was thinking, as that's how you reverse a `Comparator`.

Comment: No, negating just reverses their order, but we need them after every image that is higher than height, so +100000 does just that.

Comment: @user1096188: Good point. In that case I'd use `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: This begins to fail the closer `height` gets to 1000000.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for any typos, I don't have a compiler handy, would this work?

Grab all those >, orderB, taking the first, if null, take the max?

```
  var greaterThan = imageObj.Files.Where( f => f.Height > height );
         var imageFile = greaterThan.OrderBy( f => f.Height ).FirstOrDefault() 
                     ??  imageObj.Files.OrderBy( f => f.Height ).FirstOrDefault();
```