# How do I optionally reverse the sorting order in Linq-to-Sql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have the following code:

```
IQueryable<Guid> GetOrdered(IQueryable<Guid> ids)
{
    return from id in ids join storedId in storedIds on id equals storedId.Id
        orderby storedId.Something select id;
}
```

Now I want to introduce a parameter to `GetOrdered()` and optionally change `orderby` with `orderby descending`. Something like this:

```
IQueryable<Guid> GetOrdered(IQueryable<Guid> ids, bool descending)
{
    // how do I insert descending into the query below?
    return from id in ids join storedId in storedIds on id equals storedId.Id
        orderby storedId.Something select id;
}
```

Of course I could write two identical queries - one with `orderby` and another with `orderby descending` but that means code duplication.

Alternatively I could use a sub-statement for an unordered set and then conditionally order it [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1606482/57428) but the problem is I then need to `Select()` a specific column and that latter `Select()` will render an unordered result.

So I could try to craft a "smart" ordering condition as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9589728/57428):

```
var result = from w in widgets where w.Name.Contains("xyz")
  orderby
    flag ? w.Id : 0,
    flag ? 0 : w.Id descending
  select w;
```

but the problem is I will often have a non-numeric column as one by which I need my set ordered.

How do I conditionally reverse the sorting order under these conditions?

Comment: I don't understand why you cant use the "sub-statement with conditionall order" solution?

Comment: @Magnus: That's because it will be first "ordered", then "filtered" without any specific order.

Comment: @sharptooth If you perform a `select` after an `orderby`, the `select` doesn't change the order of the results. (Although I could be wrong, maybe LINQ-to-objects provides more of a guarantee here than LINQ-to-SQL does.)

Comment: @Rawling: How is that guaranteed?

Comment: @sharptooth I'm used to LINQ-to-objects where it's definitely true, and I'd honestly be very surprised if the same wasn't true for LINQ-to-SQL, but it seems obvious enough that I can't think how to prove it :-/

Comment: @sharptooth if you are just doing a `select` after the `orderby` why not materialize the collection after the `orderby`, than you can be sure that the order is preserver when you do the `select`.

Comment: @Magnus: If I materialize it it can consume too much memory.

Comment: @Rawling I haven't come across an example where it doesn't hold from for LINQ-to-SQL, but I don't think it is guaranteed. See for example the first paragraph of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Unfortunately the AsOrdered extension only works with ParallelQuery.

Comment: @sgmoore I'd read that as LINQ-to-SQL doesn't "preserve the order of the *source* sequence", but I'd still expect an `OrderBy` followed by a `Select` wouldn't discard the `OrderBy`. It should be quite simple to check - call an `OrderBy` followed by a `Select` and see if the SQL it generates would preserve the ordering.

Comment: @Rawling. That is how I read it as well. Obviously we are interpreting this differently. As for your check, all it will do is prove that the order is preserved for one linq statement on your current framework. It does not prove that it will work for all statements on all Framework versions (including future ones). Note I have quite a few debugging/logging statements that do this but only where I would prefer, but don't actually need, the information sorted and I have never seen a case where it hasn't worked. But until I see some indication that this is guaranteed. I don't want to rely on it.

Comment: @sgmoore And I'd be surprised if they supported ordering before a `select` in even some situations (by outputting the `orderby` rather than deliberately discarding it) when it's not possible to support it in all situations. Honesly, however, I'm most surprised by how badly this seems to be documented :D

Comment: Any solution you do will have the same problem using Linq2SQL unless you append the orderby at the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
IQueryable<Guid> GetOrdered(IQueryable<Guid> ids, bool descending = false)
{
    var results = from id in ids join storedId in storedIds on id equals storedId.Id
                  select id;

    if (descending)
       results = results.OrderByDescending(o => o.Something);
    else
       results = results.OrderBy(o => o.Something);

    return results;
}
```

This is kinda standard stuff.

However, if you need to order by something you don't actually select, you need to split the query into multiple statements. You know, construct the query step by step, like we did it back in the ADO days. First do the ordering and then specify the columns for the select. Because you don't materialize the results, it should generate only a single sql query.

It might look like this.

```
IQueryable<Guid> GetOrdered(IQueryable<Guid> ids, bool descending = false)
{
    var results = storedIds.Where(somecondition);        
    if (descending)
       results = results.OrderByDescending(o => o.Something);
    else
       results = results.OrderBy(o => o.Something);

    return results.Select(o => o.Id);
}
```

About your last sentence..

> but the problem is I will often have a non-numeric column as one by
>   which I need my set ordered.

That's true. There might be a way to overcome this (like use some factory that would generate the value to compare to based on some input), but that's really an overkill for a task like this. Sometimes the easiest solution is the best. Too generic ways of doing things can smell really bad. Don't overthink the problem ;)

Comment: This is exactly like the solution he said he _couldn't_ use.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve conditional OrderBy in Linq, you could do something like this:

```
var flag = sortOrder == "asc";

result.OrderBy(o => flag ? o.Something: "").ThenByDescending(o => flag ? "" : o.Something).ToList();
```

Works for me.