# LINQ Conditional OrderBy

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to do a conditional OrderBy but it's having no effect. The List outputs the same with default ordering.

I've tried both approaches suggested in this question [Conditional "orderby" sort order in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606454/conditional-orderby-sort-order-in-linq)

```
    var query =  _context.Groups
        .Where(gr => gr.Status != ((sbyte)ActiveStatus.DELETED) 
                    && gr.OrganisationId == user.OrganisationId 
                    && (search != null && gr.Name != null ? (gr.Name.Contains(search)) : true == true)
                    )
        .Select(GroupReportModel.Projection);


        if(!pager.Sort.HasValue || pager.Sort.Value == ((int)Sort.MODIFIED))
            query.OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Created.Date);

        if(pager.Sort.Value == ((int)Sort.NAME))    
            query.OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Name);
    
    
    pager.TotalRecords = query.Count(); 
    var list = query.Skip(pager.PageCount != null ? pager.PageCount.Value * (pager.Page.Value) : 0)
        .Take(pager.PageCount != null ? pager.PageCount.Value  : 0)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ methods do not mutate the query object, they return a new one, you need to reassign it:

```cs
if(!pager.Sort.HasValue || pager.Sort.Value == ((int)Sort.MODIFIED))
    query = query.OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Created.Date);

if(pager.Sort.Value == ((int)Sort.NAME))    
    query = query.OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Name);

....
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow what is different in this code?

Comment: @GrandMassive it reassigns the `query` variable (please look closely at the code in the `if`'s).