# Conditional Order By in Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following code:

```
if(result)
{
var query = people.OrderByDescending(person => person.Name)                
                  .Select(person => person.Name);
}

else {
var query = people.OrderBy(person => person.Name)                 
                  .Select(person => person.Name);
}
```

The only difference between this, is that if result is true, it will OrderByDescending, else OrderBy.

Is there a way to clean this up and have less redundant code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional "orderby" sort order in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606454/conditional-orderby-sort-order-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator, and change the order of the extension methods:

```
var query = people.Select(person => person.Name);
query = result ? query.OrderByDescending(p => p) 
               : query.OrderBy(p => p);
```

If you are asking for a way to actually avoid either calling `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` based on `result`, no there is not. If you have this type of code sprinkled all over the place, then I'd advise you create a helper extension method to encapsulate this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Q> OrderBy<T,Q>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T,Q> keySelector,
    bool descending)
{
     var query = source.Select(keySelector);
     return descending ? query.OrderByDescending(p => p)
                       : query.OrderBy(p => p);
}
```